# Installing Python Nlp library Spacy in windows

Tags: windows, nlp, spacy, python-wheel

I am very much impressed with the spacy documentation but i am struggling to install it in my windows 7 32 bit os ... I have tried installing it from anaconda and pip ...

Also tried to install a wheel package of it from **https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/** .... while installing the wheel file also i got unsupported message ...

- cymem-1.31.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- spacy-2.0.5-cp27-cp27m-win32_2.whl
- murmurhash-0.28.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32_2.whl
- thinc-6.10.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
- preshed-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

## Error which I got

> spacy-2.0.5-cp27-cp27m-win32_2.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Am trying for an working wheel for spacy is there any source or anyone could provide ??

Answer (score 0):

Ya Found !! The error occured because **spacy-2.0.5-cp27-cp27m-win32_2.whl** file was renamed (since redownloaded so browser renamed it)

After changing it to **spacy-2.0.5-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl** it works ... Pip uses file name for platform verification ...

Thanks for **ines** , https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1741